# VSC run code analysis __float128 is not supported on this target

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, code-analysis

Every time I run code analysis in C++ project I receive __float128 is not supported on this target

Is any possibility to turn off those kind of clang errors?

I have been searching answer for hours, but could not find anything.

My setup: Visual Studio Code V1.70.0, cmake, GCC v11.3.0., clang built with VSC, C++20

The whole error:

```
[{
    "resource": "/d:/OneDrive/Documents/Programming languages/c++/Projects/firstProject/main.cpp",
    "owner": "clang-tidy",
    "code": "clang-diagnostic-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Error while processing",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 101,
            "startColumn": 3,
            "endLineNumber": 101,
            "endColumn": 13,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/std_abs.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 102,
            "startColumn": 7,
            "endLineNumber": 102,
            "endColumn": 17,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/std_abs.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 1049,
            "startColumn": 21,
            "endLineNumber": 1049,
            "endColumn": 31,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 138,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 138,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 138,
            "startColumn": 37,
            "endLineNumber": 138,
            "endColumn": 47,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 143,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 143,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 143,
            "startColumn": 41,
            "endLineNumber": 143,
            "endColumn": 51,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 148,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 148,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 148,
            "startColumn": 42,
            "endLineNumber": 148,
            "endColumn": 52,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 153,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 153,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 153,
            "startColumn": 38,
            "endLineNumber": 153,
            "endColumn": 48,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 158,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 158,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 158,
            "startColumn": 42,
            "endLineNumber": 158,
            "endColumn": 52,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 163,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 163,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 163,
            "startColumn": 46,
            "endLineNumber": 163,
            "endColumn": 56,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 168,
            "startColumn": 22,
            "endLineNumber": 168,
            "endColumn": 32,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 168,
            "startColumn": 39,
            "endLineNumber": 168,
            "endColumn": 49,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 173,
            "startColumn": 40,
            "endLineNumber": 173,
            "endColumn": 50,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/numbers"
        },
        {
            "startLineNumber": 415,
            "startColumn": 39,
            "endLineNumber": 415,
            "endColumn": 49,
            "message": "__float128 is not supported on this target",
            "resource": "/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.3.0/type_traits"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: "Every time I run code analysis" - *What* code analysis? That could mean many different things.

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be caused by your VSCode using clang-tidy as the C/C++ extension. clang-tidy does not support __float128, so it will produce errors in the header files of the standard library.
Modify cStandard or cppStandard to a lower version in VSCode settings, such as c11 or c++14.

Answer (score 0):

I'been encounting with the same situation. But in my case gnu g++, mingw , C++11 or 17. I'been searching answer for 2 days, but couldn't find. Originally, that error is generated from a fact that __float128 is not declared' within 'std_abs.h' header file. I solved this problem by adding one line at starting point of main.cpp, like this `#define __STRICT_ANSI__` because if  `__STRICT_ANSI__` is not defined, some code related with __float128 will activate.

I hope this answer will be helpful though my poor English skills. Thanks

Comment: Still does not work :/, but thanks for willingness! Btw your English is not so poor!

Answer (score 0):

I have been encountering the same situation. But my setup was gnu14,mingw.

I have solved this problem by switching file encoding from UTF-8 to GBK and then back to UTF-8.

But I don't know why this step above works. Maybe the problem is VSC's bug.